# TIMEOUT error implementing captcha in android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, captcha, avd

Estoy implementando Google SafetyNet reCAPTCHA API en mi aplicación android, pero tengo algunos problemas con el emulador. Cuando ejecuto mi app en el emulador, el captcha me da error de TIMEOUT. Si ejecuto mi app en un dispositivo móvil, el captcha funciona bien. Tal vez falta algo en la configuración del emulador?

Comment: Hola Vanessa. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. No conozco android pero has de especificar más informacion. Tienes logs o has ejecutado el modo debug para ver qué puede estar fallando ?  Mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: El unico requisito es que tengas actualizada google play services.
Para esto puedes usar un emulador Nexus 5X que te permite
realizar las actualizaciones.

Comment: @FranciscoTixi esta actualizada, estoy usando un emulador Nexus 7 con Android Oreo.